# Keras Tuner Save Best Model

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-tuner

I am currently attempting to used keras tuner to create a model for my CNN, though I am having some issues with saving my model for future use.

As I am used to it, I could regularly just save my model with `model.save(filename)` to receive a `.model` file; however, when attempting this with code such as:

```
tuner = RandomSearch(
    build_model,
    objective = "val_accuracy",
    max_trials = 5,
    executions_per_trial = 1,
    directory = LOG_DIR
)

tuner.search(x= x_train, y= y_train, epochs= 1, batch_size=64, validation_data= (x_test, y_test))

bestModels = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=1)
highestScoreModel= models[0]

highestScoreModel.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=5, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)

highestScoreModel.save("Trained_Model")
```

I received a `Trained_Model` folder with no model within it, only the parameters. If anyone could assist me with saving the actual trained model I'd be very thankful.

================= Edit / Update ================

I have now found a way to obtain the trial_id by sifting the generated trial files. Though, when I run:

```
trial_id = getID()
tuner.save_model(trial_id=trial_id, model=highestScoreModel, step=0)
```

Nothing seems to happen, no save file appears. Again, I would be grateful for any help on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Tuner.save_model(trial_id, model, step=0)
```

where

- `trial_id` is your model trial number
- `model` is your trained model
- and `step` is epochs numbers

Comment: Thank you for this, I've just realised this is in the docs so sorry for the question! Though, I am having some issues in attaining the trail ID of the model, any suggestions?